# how to properly redirect to another page after post request in ionic angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to redirect to another page after user sign up in ionic angular but i'm getting nothing code below:

```
    this.http.post('http://127.0.1.1:3001/api/signup',user)
        .subscribe({
            next: (res) => {if(res == "OK"){this.router.navigateByUrl("/otp")}},
            error: error => console.error(error),
            complete: () => this.router.navigateByUrl("/otp")
   });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like

```
    .subscribe((res) => {
        if (res == "OK") {
          this.router.navigate(['otp']);
        } else {
          this.errmsgshow = true;
          this.errmsg = res.msg;
        }
```